# How to remove search results with jQuery after remove the characters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So I am a back-end developer with zero `jQuery` or `JavaScript` knowledge, I managed to find a piece of code to create a Ajax search like feature. I bundled it with my `Django` model and it works. However after I remove characters in the input bar, the results are still displayed.

I would like to see when the input is none, the results also go away. I use this piece of code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready( function() {
        $( '#q' ).keyup( function() {
            q = $( '#q' ).val();
            $( '#results' ).html( '&nbsp;' ).load( '{% url 'search' %}?q=' + q );
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: How do you clear the input? Your function basically calls the server whenever you are in the input field and release a key. What does your server return when q is empty?

Comment: This should work, because a delete or backspace should still trigger a `keyup` event afaik. I'd like to understand why or how this doesn't work - however, as a last resort changing the `.keyup` to `.change` is a reasonable thing to try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code. I haven't tested.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready( function() {
        $( '#q' ).keyup( function() {
            q = $( '#q' ).val();
            if(q.length > 0)
               $( '#results' ).html( '&nbsp;' ).load( '{% url 'search' %}?q=' + q );
            else
               $( '#results' ).html( '&nbsp;' )
        });
    });
</script>
```